# I'm using FQL to count all the comments on a given webpage... but it's limited at 25?

Tags: limit, facebook-fql, facebook-comments

Where $PfullURL is a webpage, I used the following approach to get what I thought were all the comments so I could parse the data for unique user comments per day.

```
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids='.$PfullURL;
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
$fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);
```

This limits my returns to 25, and I'm not sure how to re-wirte this query so I get ALL the comments on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `&limit=200` to your `$PfullURL;`

Comment: A life saver is what you are.